# Bootstrap collapse after set height

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

What I'm trying to achieve is relatively simple after a set height I'm looking to collapse a div using Bootstrap default attributes. Below I have written the javascript to trigger after a set height but what I'm unsure on is how to trigger the collapse with the id of `#more`.

```js
function testScroll(ev) {

  if (window.pageYOffset > 1100) alert('User has scrolled at least 400 px!');
}
```

```html
<div id="more" class="collapse">test</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [collapse function](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/) as defined in the bootstrap docs, by providing it the element id. You can also read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp).

```
function testScroll(ev){
    if(window.pageYOffset>1100) {
      alert('User has scrolled at least 400 px!');
      $('more').collapse('hide');
    } else {
      alert('User has not scrolled at least 400 px!');
      $('more').collapse('show');
    }
}


<div id="more" class="collapse">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you don't know how to select and change the class of the item `#more`

```
var collapse = function() {

  // select the element that has the id #more
  var element = document.getElementById('more');

  // now you can, for exemple change its class
  // that's where you can apply a different css class to collapse the div
  element.setAttribute('class','anotherClass');

}
```

Comment: `function testScroll(ev){
    if(window.pageYOffset>1100)
  
var collapse = function() {
  var element = document.getElementById('more');
  element.setAttribute('collapse.in');

}
}
window.onscroll=testScroll`
 I would of thought this would have worked?